# Dados se sobrepondo no eixo x do gráfico

Tags: mysql, python, matplotlib

Preciso colocar uma série de datas(timestamp) que estão armazenadas em um bd no eixo x de um gráfico, o problema é que as datas se sobrepõem e fica impossível uma análise eficiente. Segue o códgio:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import MySQLdb as mdb
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.dates as dates

con = mdb.connect('localhost', 'testuser', '*******', 'testdb')
with con:
    f = []
    cur = con.cursor()
    conversor = dates.strpdate2num('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
    a = cur.execute("SELECT Ping FROM Pings WHERE Enderecos ='186.209.34.78'")
    a = cur.fetchall()    
    row = cur.execute("SELECT Timestamp FROM Pings WHERE Enderecos = '186.209.34.78'")
    for i in range(cur.rowcount):   
        row= cur.fetchone()[0]   
        f.append(conversor(row))
    plt.xlabel("Timestamp")
    plt.ylabel("Ping")
    plt.plot_date(f,a)
    plt.title("186.209.34.78")
    plt.show()
```

[image: Resultado:]

Com zoom:[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: E se você tentar reduzir o tamanho da fonte: `matplotlib.rcParams.update({'font.size': 10})`?

Comment: Acho que não tem como fugir de diminuir a fonte como explicado no post acima. Além disso, não sei como é gerado esse timestamp do eixo `x` mas vc poderia tentar deixar só o dia e o mês ou então apenas 2 digitos do ano. Se o timestamp for criado com alguma função de `datetime` ou algo do tipo e não diretamente pela `mpl` é só fazer o processamento da string pra transformar ela em um formato mais "agradável" (menor). Para tratar essa data, pode usar `data = '2017-05-28'
data2 = ''.join([x+'-' if len(x)<4 else data[2:4] for x in reversed(data.split('-'))])`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Acredito que você possa rotacionar esse texto, usando:

```
plt.xticks(rotation=20)
```

Resultado:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Exatamente o que eu precisava, obrigado! :)